# Can I post the configuration that I'm thinking about buying?

Tags: discussion

I would like to receive feedback from the setup I'm thinking of buying (I chose each component myself) and hear from you guys if I'm buying something that might be incompatible, less ideal than some other component and also a comparison from what I'm leaving behind (current configuration) against what I'm going to buy.

Are those things I'm seeking on topic for this community?

Comment: With the current scope, I don't believe this is on topic. It's worth discussing again, though - it's possible that we can answers these kinds of questions and answer them well.

Comment: @Undo I could swear that it would be on topic =/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this would work out. The way I'm thinking such a question would be posed, it sounds like it's a technical support or too broad of question. This would fall into a question like so:

> I've purchased MOBO from MANUFACTURER A. I've gotten 8GB of MANUFACTURER B RAM, and a MANUFACTURER C video card (with 4GB of Video Memory). I also have a MANUFACTURER D processor (MODEL NUMBER).
>
> This is to replace my existing machine with the following specs: [list of specs here].
>
> Will this new machine be better in terms of CRITERIA 1, CRITERIA 2 and CRITERIA 3? If not, what should I get instead?

The problem I see with this type of question is that if the answer to "will this be better?" is "No", then you can get recommendations for *any* component in the system. We prefer each question be limited to a single component.

In general, if you are *upgrading*, your performance should be better than the old machine. A new processor is usually faster than an older one. RAM is cheaper now than it was last time you purchased, so you can probably get more. Video cards are always getting better. So, that means the "will this be better?" question *should* be a 'Yes', a majority of the time.

If I'm wrong about how you intend to phrase your question, provide an edit to your post with an example. Until then, though, based on the assumption above, I don't think this type of question will work here.

Comment: It kind goes exactly like that, but to be honest my CPU of choice, which even though it's 4 years newer, it's actually not better than the old one. Due to economic instability, RAM is actually more expensive now (for me). The rest goes exactly like you posed.

Comment: Instead of posting an overly broad question then, focus on each individual component. Post a question about the CPUs you are considering, then RAM, etc. In each question, refer to others (and mention which component you selected to purchase from those answers). That will help to ensure compatibility.