# why not 'hardware'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems that many new posters' questions are given the close for asking about hardware, giving the reason that the site is for 'hardware recommendations' only, and its scope doesn't extend to other aspects of 'hardware', such as technical queries.

Example:
[Can I post the configuration that I'm thinking about buying?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/can-i-post-the-configuration-that-im-thinking-about-buying)

I think this is driving away users of this site, or discouraging new ones to join or post questions.

Why not increase scope to all of hardware?

Comment: Chat's better for open ended discussion. Superuser and other sites are better for tech support type questions

Answer (score 5):

The idea behind the site isn't to be technical support for all hardware. There are other sites on the network that can absorb some of those types of questions.

The goal of *this* site, is to help users pick out new [hardware](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware). This site, and its [sister site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) are built to provide high quality *recommendations* for users that know the functionality they want, but not the product that will provide it.

We should not increase our scope to become a technical support waste land.

Comment: Might add that technical support queries are for [su] and not HW.se, and I've been finding a few (and casing CVs) of them around recently.